# Should Kevin Durant be benched?

Tags: probability

Kevin Durant is a world-class basketball player. He averages roughly 2 fouls for every 40 minutes of game play.

Per NBA rules, you must stop playing after picking up 6 fouls. Supposing Kevin Durant has 4 fouls with 20 minutes remaining in a game:

a) if he tries to play all 20 remaining minutes, what are the odds he acquires two more fouls and has to leave the game?

b) if he were to sit on the bench for 5 minutes (leaving 15 remaining), then what would the odds be?

c) if not 5, is there an ideal number for B in generating a greater likelihood of attaining more minutes than A?

Comment: Hint: Model this as a Poisson process with intensity 1 foul per 5 minute period.

Comment: Are we assuming the foul occurrences are uniformly distributed throughout the game? That is, are fouls equally likely to occur at any time?

Comment: Also, is this homework?

Comment: @Macro For the purposes of this question, any minute is as likely to draw a foul as the next. Also, it's not homework - I'm having a debate with friends and I'm not a mathematician.

Comment: Under mild assumptions (that I won't state :)), benching a player with foul trouble strictly decreases the expected number of minutes the player plays; the intuition is that you are voluntarily imposing on yourself the very penalty that you are trying to avoid. All you are doing is shifting their expected foul-out time distribution by the amount of time you bench them. But NBA coaches are willing to let their leads evaporate or their opponents blow them out because god forbid they let their star player foul out.

Comment: I think the reason the practice persists is because a lot of people think that not all minutes in basketball are created equal, and so it is better to "save" your stars for the end of the game. There is some empirical evidence that they are correct, but I would argue this is sort of a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Comment: @Guy, I think there's something to be said for taking a brief break to 1) calm down so you quit going after a particularly annoying opponent, 2) rest up a little bit so you're not uncoordinated and flailing limbs everywhere and 3) get off the officials' radar. For those reasons, I would guess that fouls are at least reasonably "streaky?" Anyone have some data on that?

Comment: @Guy The assumption coaches are making by benching players is that being in foul trouble restricts the way you play. You've got to defend a little more cautiously to avoid the risk of further fouls. Benching a star gives them a rest and brings on a bench player who knows they will play few minutes anyway, so can defend at full intensity knowing that a foul won't have a huge impact. A bench player might play as well as a star in foul trouble and benching ensures all star minutes are played at high intensity. That is the theory anyway. Of course, the OP has asked us to ignore all this...

Comment: @Bogdanovist if the player has to alter his play so much that he is playing worse than a bench player, perhaps he should just play the same way instead of dancing around fouls. Put the bench player in **if**/when the star fouls out. I would discuss the other points you made more (in particular resting and the psychological issues Matt pointed out), but I'm trying to stay away from things that have little hope of being formalized mathematically since otherwise we would be discussing basketball instead of statistics/probability :)

Comment: This question is obviously a curiosity and not homework.  I find it very interesting.Jim Albert got men hooked up with a writer who had questions about Jeremy Lin's sudden rise to success witht he Knicks and he interviewed me about it.  I worked out an estimate of the probability htat he could have accomplished what he did in his first six games and got quote on it in an article.  I am not going to attempt this question yet.  It seems very interesting but also difficult and may require making a lot of assumptions.

Comment: I think game 3 showed that the Thunder are in trouble against the Heat when Durant is on the bench even for just 5 minutes.  James, Bosch and Wade can really exploit the Thunder's weaknessess when he is out.  That showed when they took him out with 4 fouls. It might be best to wait until he pciks up number five before they sit him down because the Thunder loss their momentum. If he fouls out with even just 2 minutes left however , that can be even more disasterous.

Comment: @everyone Just wanted to log in and say I appreciate the discussion! If anyone could provide an answer to A, B or C I'd appreciate that too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has actually been some research on this(!). Here's a paper by [Maymin et al. (2012)](http://philipmaymin.com/papers/Maymin%20Maymin%20and%20Shen%20-%20Early%20Foul%20Trouble%20-%20IJSF%202012.pdf), ([SSRN Link)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1736633). They actually look at win-loss statistics instead of just trying to maximize the number of minutes a player plays. They argue that:

- Getting into foul trouble causes a player to play measurably worse, and so
- It's rational to yank a player with Q+1 fouls (where Q is the present quarter)

There's a shorter [piece](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2012/06/21/foul_trouble_in_nba_finals_are_the_heat_and_the_thunder_coaches_acting_rationally_by_pulling_durant_and_other_players_.html) of Slate, which is where I found the original reference. Enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

If we stick rigidly to the assumption "any minute is as likely to draw a foul as the next" then we can model this simply as a Poisson process. The results are shown in the figure below.
[image: Probability of Durant making 2 more fouls]

The vertical axis shows the probability that Durant has not been fouled out after playing the number of minutes shown on the horizontal axis.

Reading off the numbers at each time asked, there is a 74% probability of Durant going the distance if he attempts to play all 20 minutes. If he is benched for 5 minutes, he will only be able to play for a maximum of 15 minutes and the probability he will not foul out in that time increases to 83%.

As for part c), there is no trade off involved. Durant should never be benched if the goal is to maximise the number of minutes played.

For what it's worth I don't think that the assumption of fouls being a Poisson process is true, but then the result of the analysis would entirely depend of what other assumptions are being made.

Comment: Thank you! The "Minutes" axis is "minutes rested", not "minutes played", correct?

Comment: @SamuelHulick No No! The minutes axis is minutes played before fouling out. This doesn't have to be consecutive minutes, so if he plays for 5, gets benched for 5, then plays another 5 he has played 10 minutes in total, then reading off from the graph he will have 92% chance of not being fouled out in the period.

Comment: @SamuelHulick I've edited the response to make the meaning of the graph clearer. I hope that helps.

Comment: One reason for benching the player that I think has not yet been mentioned is that when a player gets in foul trouble the opponent will exploit the situation by directing the offensive attack toward getting the player to pick up another foul.  Because of this strategy and other basketball strategy that changes throughout the game the Poisson model is not really appropriate.

Comment: There was some discussion on SportCenter this morning regarding the Thunder's decision to bench Durant during the last 5 minutes of the 3rd quarter (after a 4th foul) where a 9 point lead evaporated and turned into a 2 point deficit that was crucial toward Miami's win.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I completely agree that a Poisson model is a terrible model for this situation. The question asked us to make that assumption though, so that's what I presented. I don't think the answer sheds any light on the real world question of who should be benched when.

Comment: @Bogdanovist The OP did not say to make any particular assumption but you can't answer the question without making some kind of assumption.  I have no objection to your answer which illustrates how to explicitly answer the question under the Poisson assumption realistic or not.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Sorry yes you're right, the original question was ambiguous. I forgot that it was in a comment that the OP specified "For the purposes of this question, any minute is as likely to draw a foul as the next". If that is considered as part of the question then the assumptions are all made. It's clear that this describes a Poisson process, even if the OP didn't use the explicit technical term.